# I am trying to calculate the random numbers roll of the dice in a loop till a double is rolled. Nothing happening when I load the page

Tags: javascript, random, while-loop

I am trying to calculate the random numbers roll of the dice in a loop till a double is rolled. Nothing happening when I load the page.
Here is my code.

```
 var roll1 = randomInteger(1,6);
 var roll2 = randomInteger(1,6);
 while(roll1 != roll2){ 
    var roll1 = randomInteger(1,6);
    var roll2 = randomInteger(1,6);

    document.write(+roll1+ " - " +roll2+ );

}
document.write("<br><br><b>Doubles obtained" );
```

Comment: lose `var` inside your `while` loop. You're probably interrupting scope. (Take that back, looks like the hoisting works (though I still think `var` within is incorrect/confusing at some level).)

Comment: Where is the `randomInteger()` function? What do you see in the console?

Comment: lose `+` signs in `document.write`, also, you should try `console.log` instead

Answer (score 1):

There were three things I changed:

1. `Math.floor(Math.random() *6);` instead of `randomInteger(1,6);`
2. remove `+` from `document.write(+roll1+ " - " +roll2+ );`
3. use `writeln` instead of `write`

   ```
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h3>Script</h3>
     <script language="javascript">
       document.writeln("Start ..." +"<br>");

       var roll1 = Math.floor(Math.random() *6);
       var roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() *6);

       while(roll1 != roll2){ 
         roll1 = Math.floor(Math.random() *6);
         roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() *6);

         document.writeln(roll1+ " - " +roll2 +"<br>");
      }

     </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

The third point seems obsolete :) ... and the second two `var`'s as well (removed them).

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, it could be a couple of things:

1. `document.write`
   `document.write*` has been deprecated/killed off in recent versions of [X]HTML (as it was a very insecure method of outputting content). If you're basing your decision purely off "I don't see anything", this could be because the browse itself is blocking the call. (You also have a syntax error within given your over-use of concatenation operators (`+`) which doesn't help).
2. `randomInteger`
   I have no way to validate how/if this is a working function, but I'd still double-check the return value. (Maybe check your function against the one I've provided below)

Having said that, from what I have below, I see no reason why this shouldn't work:

```js
function log(t){ document.getElementById('db').innerHTML += t + '\r\n'; }

function randomInteger(l,h){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + l;
}

var roll1 = randomInteger(1,6);
var roll2 = randomInteger(1,6);
log('1: ' + roll1 + '; 2:' + roll2);
while (roll1 != roll2){
    var roll1 = randomInteger(1,6);
    var roll2 = randomInteger(1,6);
    log('1: ' + roll1 + '; 2:' + roll2);
}
log('Doubles obtained');
```

```html
<pre id="db"><pre>
```

As an aside, though I did leave it here for the demo (as I was wrong in a comment about how the variable may be scoped), I would avoid using `var` every time you need the variable. This lends itself easily to unclear code, and, as you do cross scope boundaries, you'll find yourself in trouble.

As a value-add, check out [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to understand a bit more about when/how to declare variables (and how JavaScript handles this internally).

Comment: Yes, they get hoisted, but what happens on subsequent iterations of the loop. Do the values get updated properly?

Comment: Yes, they're [updated correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/db9q1bak/1/). If my original comment was the root of all this, I apologize. I did edit is shortly thereafter, but the re-declaration has no effect on the outcome. You're not crossing a scope boundary, therefore behavior is kept.

Comment: No, not at all. Without seeing all of the relevant code it was difficult to make a determination. The weird variable declarations seemed an obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

i think its because of document.write. it rewrites the whole document with

> doubles obtained

, removing any previous text.

Comment: `document.write` can be called numerous times; it's not the same as `.innerHTML` (where multiple assignments without concatenation would clear previous values).

Comment: And although I appreciate the edit, the additional `var` declarations were kept in the code snippet on purpose (then called out in the paragraph thereafter). But good looking out. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a year, but I believe this is the simplest way to get what you are looking for:

```
var linebreak = "<p></p>";
var roll1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var rolling = true;

while(rolling) {
    if(roll1 === roll2) {
        document.write(linebreak + "Doubles! You rolled: " + roll1 + ", " + roll2);
        rolling = false;
    }
    else {
        document.write(linebreak + "Rerolling... " + roll1 + ", " + roll2);
        var roll1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the `randomInteger` function, I have to assume that there is an issue with declaring the same variables twice (`roll1` and `roll2`).

I would try this:

```
var roll1 = randomInteger(1,6);
var roll2 = randomInteger(1,6);
while(roll1 != roll2){ 
    roll1 = randomInteger(1,6); // <--- removed "var"
    roll2 = randomInteger(1,6); // <--- removed "var"

    document.write(+roll1+ " - " +roll2+ );
} 
document.write("<br><br><b>Doubles obtained" );
```

I'm not even sure what the effect of your structure would be. You have declared the same variable names twice within the same scope. (JavaScript has function level scope -- not block level scope.

Comment: Javascript does not have distinct scopes inside `while` loops. Don't let incorrect comments sway your answers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That is EXACTLY what I said. Please pay attention.

Comment: If that's exactly what you're saying, then *I have to assume that there is an issue with declaring the same variables twice* does not make sense.

Comment: Please google "variable hoisting" and stop thinking removing the `var` keywords would solve the problem.

Comment: Redeclaring those variables within the `while` makes no sense at all, b/c as you said _Javascript does not have distinct scopes inside while loops._ Sheesh! Please step away from the keyboard.

Comment: "Redeclaring" those variables actually has no effect. See that hoisting thing I was referring to. As for stepping away from the keyboard -- I'm not the one posting incorrect answers here.

Comment: I'm well aware. Thanks for completely missing the point, and failing to add anything constructive to this conversation.